# my SVG won't resize in IE11

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

Here is my example:    `jsfiddle.net/ra1u5y23/8/`
I dont understand why my svg's (first three images) wont resize properly in IE11.
The last three svgs (kiwi) work fine in IE11. (not tested with other browsers)
I resized my svg's with inkscape.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Just a guess: Your SVG is missing the `viewBox`. Maybe try to add that one.

Answer (score 2):

Your SVGs need to have a `viewBox` attribute.  This tells the browser the dimensions of your SVG contents so it knows how much to scale it.

By default Inkscape doesn't add a viewBox.  You could manually add a viewBox yourself, but the easiest solution is probably just to load your blueprint SVG back into Inkscape and save it out again as an "Optimized SVG".  You will get a dialog where you need to check "Enable viewboxing".

Your file should now scale like the kiwi symbol does.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i would upvote your answer if i could.

My problem now is that i have svgs in different sizes.
They are fit into a div container.
Some svgs are wider than others. I want to keep the same scale between the svgs.
Have you got any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I get quite what you mean.  Anyway, it sounds like a different problem which should probably have it's own question.  Try asking a new question with an example of what you mean.